# How to position to right and have items below one and other in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I'm trying to position social icons on my website. Ideally, on the right side, fixed in the middle.

My problem is that the best I can get out of it is when they are on top of each other instead of below. 
I tried just setting the margins, flexbox, fixed positioning, but I don't find the right combination of settings for this.

```css
.section #icon-bar {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: 'Raleway DOts', sans-serif;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

section #icon-bar li {
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  display: block;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 30px;
  list-style: none;
}

section #icon-bar li div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  color: #74d4b3;
  font-size: 3.4em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 120px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul id="icon-bar">
    <li>
      <div class="facebook">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/>
          <i class=" fa fa-facebook " aria-hidden="true "></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <span>Facebook</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="linkedin ">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/ ">
          <i class="fa fa-linkedin " aria-hidden="true "></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <span>LinkedIn</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="github ">
        <a href="https://github.com/ ">
          <i class="fa fa-github " aria-hidden="true "></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <span>Github</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

I would like to have each icon on the right side, in the middle, each under each other. Right now, they are on top of each other. 
Thank you

Comment: I'd start by removing `position: fixed;` from the `li`

Comment: maybe `display:inline-block;` or `float:right`

Comment: thank you, then they are below each other, but on the wrong side. But it's a very good point, thanks

Comment: @Stender thanks, both of these result in them being next to each other, not below anymore. so floats to the right but they are horizontally next to each other. Or the same with inline-block, but on the left then. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted them next to eachother :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you need to `position: fixed`  to the section, and let the others work on its own.

And also you need to change `.section` to `section` on your css.

This might help

```css
section{
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

section #icon-bar{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway DOts', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

section #icon-bar li {
  text-align: center;
  display:block;
  width: 80px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
section #icon-bar li div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  color: #74d4b3;
  font-size: 3em;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<section>
  <ul id="icon-bar">
    <li>
      <div class="facebook">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <span>Facebook</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="linkedin">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
          <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <span>LinkedIn</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="github">
        <a href="https://github.com/">
          <i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <span>Github</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```